# Fill Color Not Showing in Plotly due to Small Values

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataset, I'm practicing with. I made it 60,000 lines long and the values in each line are relatively small. So when I look at it in a bar chart it doesn't look like there is fill and I'd really like to almost see it as a solid line/totaled amount. Also the reason I don't summarize it prior to charting it is that in practice I'd really like to be able to filter for different levels of data and for it to show up summarized. Any solutions to make a chart like this scalable?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Orange", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})
#this is just me trying to make a large dataset
df_append =[]
for i in range(10010):
    data = df
    df_append.append(data)
df = pd.concat(df_append)



fig = px.bar(df, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color='City')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't improve with a horizontal bar graph, so this is a no-brainer.

Comment: Is there any change if you sort th e df before to graph ? df.sort_values(by='City', ascending=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks like you are seeing only thé separator lines, I think you need to perform a groupby before to plot

```
df=df.groupby(['City', 'Fruit'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out another way. I just put the group in my script in a way that every time someone updates the filter it updates my grouping.